# Proving and visualizing $\mathbf 1_{(x,x+a]}(y) = \mathbf 1_{[y-a,y)}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Here is a trick from one of the proofs in probability:

$$\iint \mathbf 1_{(x,x+a]}(y) \ \lambda(dx) \ \mathbb P(dy) = \iint \mathbf 1_{[y-a,y)}(x) \ \lambda(dx) \ \mathbb P(dy)$$

for $a>0$. So basically $$\mathbf 1_{(x,x+a]}(y) = \mathbf 1_{[y-a,y)}(x)$$

for any $x,y \in \mathbb R $.

I have never seen the trick before and the only proof I came up with was to consider four cases: whether $y \in (x,x+a], x \in [y-a,y)$, which is quite clumsy.

Is there a better proof? Is there a way to visualize it (in order to remember the way it goes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\mathbf 1_{(x,x+a]}(y)=1\iff x\lt y\leqslant x+a\iff y-a\leqslant x\lt y\iff \mathbf 1_{[y-a,y)}(x)=1$$

Comment: I was just typing up something nearly identical but you beat me by a few seconds!

Comment: @CameronWilliams: don't forget account for the fact that typing $\leqslant$ instead of $\le$ requires 6 more symbols